# showing installed apps list in gridview which is in dialog - not working

Tags: android, gridview, dialog, customdialog, installed-applications

I am trying to show installed apps list in dialog , onclick of a button. The apps list should be in gridview.

My code is as follows

```
mapapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {


          loadApps();

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
             LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   
                     getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);   
                                     View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorydialog,   
                                                                    (ViewGroup)   findViewById(R.id.layout_root));   

            dialog.setTitle("Title...");


             GridView mGrid = (GridView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
                mGrid.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(MainActivity.this));

                mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()   
                {   
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,   
                int position, long id) {   



                                }   
                            });   
      }
    });
```

the methods

```
        private void loadApps() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
        }
```

adapter is as follows

```
public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
             private Context mContext;   
            public AppsAdapter(Context context) {

                mContext = context;
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ImageView i;

                if (convertView == null) {
                    i = new ImageView(mContext);
                    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                    i.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(50, 50));
                } else {
                    i = (ImageView) convertView;
                }

                ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
                i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

                return i;
            }


            public final int getCount() {
                return mApps.size();
            }

            public final Object getItem(int position) {
                return mApps.get(position);
            }

            public final long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
        }
```

No error and nothing is shown.
Please suggest me where I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer

for any one who need this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

                          loadApps();
                  showDialog(CATEGORY_ID);     

          }
        });
```

and the methods used are as follows

```
private void loadApps() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

            mAppsold=getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

          mApps = getUserInstalledApps(this);

        }



          private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
                return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true
                        : false;
            }


        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {     

            switch(id) {     

            case CATEGORY_ID:     

             AlertDialog.Builder builder;     
                Context mContext = this;     

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);     
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.categorydialog,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));     
                GridView gridview = (GridView)layout.findViewById(R.id.gridview);     
                gridview.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter(this));     

                gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()     
                {  
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,int position, long id) { 

                        String now=mApps.get(position).getPackageName();

                        Intent mainIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(now);
                        if(mainIntent!=null)
                        {
                            mainIntent = mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                                                   .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                        }

                     }     
                });  

                builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);     
                builder.setView(layout);     
                dialog = builder.create();    
                dialog.setTitle("Select the Map App" );
                break;     
            default:     
                dialog = null;     
            }     
            return dialog;     
        } 




        public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
             private Context mContext;   
             LayoutInflater inflater;
            public AppsAdapter(Context context) {

                mContext = context;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolder holder;

                if (convertView == null) {

                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content, null); 
                     convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));  
                      holder = new ViewHolder();  
                      holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);  
                         holder.icon = (ImageView )convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);  
                         convertView.setTag(holder);  

                } else {

                      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
                }


                holder.icon.setAdjustViewBounds(true);  
                holder.icon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);     
                holder.icon.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);  
                holder.title.setText(mApps.get(position).getAppName());  
                holder.icon.setImageDrawable(mApps.get(position).getAppIcon());  


                return convertView; 
            }

            class ViewHolder {  
                TextView title;  
                ImageView icon;  
            }  

            public final int getCount() {
                return mApps.size();
            }

            public final Object getItem(int position) {
                return mApps.get(position);
            }

            public final long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }
        }

         public boolean isPackageExisted(String targetPackage){
                List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
                PackageManager pm;
                    pm = getPackageManager();        
                    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
                    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
                if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(targetPackage)) return true;
                }        
                return false;
            }


         public ArrayList<ApplicationInfoStruct> getUserInstalledApps(Context context)
            {
                try
                {
                    mApps = new ArrayList<ApplicationInfoStruct>();
                    packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
                    for(int i = 0; i<packs.size();i++)
                    {
                        p1 = packs.get(i);
                        if (p1.versionName == null) {
                            continue ;
                        }
                        if((packs.get(i).applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) ==1)
                        {

                        }else
                        {
                            appInfoStruct= new ApplicationInfoStruct();

                            appInfoStruct.setAppName(p1.applicationInfo.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString().trim());
                            appInfoStruct.setPackageName(p1.packageName);
                            appInfoStruct.setActivityInfo(p1.activities);
                            appInfoStruct.setVersionName(p1.versionName.toString().trim());
                            appInfoStruct.setVersionCode(p1.versionCode);
                            appInfoStruct.setSourceDir(p1.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
                            //appInfoStruct.setDate(p1.lastUpdateTime);
                            appInfoStruct.setAppIcon(p1.applicationInfo.loadIcon(context.getPackageManager()));

                            mApps.add(appInfoStruct);
                        }

                    }

                    return mApps;
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Exception in getUserInstallApps()", e.getMessage());
                    return mApps;
                }
            }
```

Thats it.
This generates a list of app view in gridview inside a dialog.